# Filter on boolean with NULL (unset) value

Tags: views

Client wants to hide some published content from specific Views displays.

Unpublishing the content is not an option: it needs to remain accessible.

I added a boolean `exclude_from_view` field to several content types.

I planned to add a boolean filter to exclude content from the necessary displays if this field's value was `TRUE`, but I was surprised to find that when I did so, Views returned no results at all. Setting the boolean filter to `NOT FALSE` had the same result.

This is happening because the field has been added to the existing content without a default value, so the field returns `NULL`, which is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. (In PHP, `NULL` is a "falsy" value, but apparently not to Views.)

A little research reveals that a lot of other people have complained about this problem.

Some of them think that boolean fields not set on entities should be considered `FALSE`, not `NULL`.

Others wish that `NULL` fields could be treated as `TRUE`.

Still others think that Views UI should offer filtering options for "Treat `NULL` as `FALSE`" or "Treat `NULL` as `TRUE`." (This is a cool idea but it requires patching core, which I'm not necessarily opposed to if it is the best way forward.)

What should I do?

**UPDATE 2019-11-13:**

Kudos to @no-sssweat for coming up with a viable workaround, which I upvoted below.

I'm still hoping for a better answer because I'm not satisfied with the user experience of the "checkboxes/radio buttons" field widget.

If I just use one value, it shows up as two radio buttons, for **N/A** and **Yes**. Adding a **No** option doesn't make it much better:
[image: Works, but UX is not ideal]

I think the client would really prefer a boolean checkbox, so I'm holding out for an answer that will give me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for posterity, here's the approach I ended up using:

The [Field Defaults](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_defaults) contrib module allowed me to set all `null` values for the new field in pre-existing content, so I was able to use the boolean checkbox I wanted.

[image: Screenshot of Field Defaults user interface, exposed in field config]

There's no need to patch core to deal with this, because it won't happen again with newly-created content. As soon as the node is saved, the field has a sensible default value.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, I was able to replicate the issue.

> Some of them think that Boolean fields not set on entities should be
>   considered FALSE, not NULL.
>
> Others wish that NULL fields could be treated as TRUE.

Seems like patching core catered towards your needs would make some people unhappy. Unless you add, a new option, an *Is Empty (NULL)* to it.

---

A work around solution is to use List (text) OR List (integer)
I set mine to `1 | yea`

You could make it a select box by switching the field widget from list to checkboxes

Then in Views filter you just set to *is none of* and it will return all nodes that are not set to "yea".

[image]

---

OR better yet you can select *Is Empty (Null)*

[image]

Comment: Interesting workaround. Can’t filter on NULL because after nodes are edited, the field has a value, but “Is none of” might work.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I found another approach (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288289/80164), but your insights were worth an upvote.